# Timezone is UTC infact of changing it in settings.py file

Tags: django, heroku, timezone

My app is showing the timezone.now() as UTC time when I see it in Heroku scheduler. Also I built a custom manage.py command to test it but it still shows UTC time.

Here is my settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Here is my personalied manage.py command
managemet/commaands/abhiwaqt.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.apps import apps
from Directory.utils import *

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help="Refresh models and its fields."

    def handle(self,*args, **options):
        try:
            print(timezone.now())
            
        except:
            raise CommandError("Something went wrong")
```

Infact of setting TIME_ZONE='Asia/Kolkata' I am getting this issue.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably good practice to keep your back end using UTC so everything is uniform and handles daylight savings and you simply handle the changes when displaying to the user in `templates` or `views`. If you want timezone support (since it is disabled by default) use the setting `USE_TZ = True`. Take a look at the docs for more in depth explanation on this topic.[enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/)

Comment: Hey, but my system is now scaled according to logic considering the current time in my timezone. Also i have kept USE_TZ=True still the error persists.

Comment: Oh so in your entire project you handled your times as if they were your time zone instead of UTC? The best thing to do is to change all that logic, all you need to do is make a function that takes UTC time and returns your local time. Then go through your code and replace all the calls to get datetime with that function. This will ensure you don't have any daylight saving issues etc.

Comment: Ok, that's what the last option is! Thanks